# Streaming video from AWS S3 to IOS App using AVPlayer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uicollectionview, video-streaming, avplayer

i'm trying to build an app that streams videos in a `UICollectionView` using `AVPlayer` just in Instagram or Vine app.

i am using AWS S3 cloud storage(Amazon Web Services) to store my video files. i do manage to stream the video but every time a new cell is presented the video takes about 1-2 seconds until the video is playing, also the streaming sometimes gets stuck. i'm getting a feeling that beside just uploading the video to the server(in my case AWS), there is some kind of a job that happens in the server, maybe decoding,transcoding or something like that. i saw this link that offers some kind of services that suppose to improve the streaming performance. 
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

my question: is one of those services is the right solution?
is just uploading the video to AWS suppose to be enough for high performance? maybe there is a way to preload a video and when the cell appears it will start the video immediately?

if you guys know any good guides for stream video in IOS with high performance.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In order to gain high performance downloads you should be serving the content via CloudFront (or a different CDN). A CDN caches the content close to the users, reduces hops between the requestor and the service, and is generally more reliable about serving files.